# How bad are Parallel nodes in a Behaviour Tree?

Tags: function, performance, artificial-intelligence

I have been told that Parallel nodes in Behaviour Trees are to be avoided at all cost. Is this really the case?

If so can you please explain why they are so bad, and how I can get the same effect but in a more optimised way?

Comment: hi, perhaps might be of interest https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/137908/how-much-logic-should-be-in-an-individual-behaviour-tree-node

Comment: Thank you! That will be of help. @jspcal